# why Rudin say that $E_i$ are not necessarily disjoint in the Vitali - Caratheodory theorem?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have some confusion regarding Rudin RCA book,  [page number 56](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkDie.png)

**Theorem 2.25  The Vitali - Caratheodory theorem**

In the proof it is written that  we see that there are measurable set $E_i$ (not necessarily disjoint) and constant $c_i >0$ such that   $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i\chi_{E_i}(x)$  for all $x \in  X$

My confusion : why Rudin say that $E_i$ are not necessarily disjoint?

**My thinking** :  If $E_i$ are not disjoint  then it will  contradicts the definition of  simple function

If $E_1\cap E_2\cap ...\cap E_n =\emptyset $  then  $E_i= \{x : s(x)= c_i\} \implies f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i\chi_{E_i}(x) $

If $E_1\cap E_2\cap ...\cap E_n \neq\emptyset $  then  $E_i= \{x : s(x)\neq c_i\}\implies  f(x)\neq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i\chi_{E_i}(x)$

Comment: What are the hypotheses about $f$?

Comment: @tomasz  It is given that  $f \in L^1(\mu)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's not claiming that the sets cannot be disjoint, only that they may not be.

Indeed, there is no reason for that to be true: the sets $E_i$ come from the characteristic functions whose linear combinations you use to get the simple functions $t_n$ such that $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n$. You know absolutely nothing about $t_n$ besides the fact that they are non-negative, simple, and add up to $f$.

In most cases, it is impossible to choose $E_i$ to be disjoint: otherwise, each of their linear combinations could only have countably many distinct values. On the other hand, if you happen to have a function which does only have countably many distinct values, it is quite easy to find such $E_i$.